# Transparent UART function for Bluetooth low Energy (BLE)

Tags: swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, btle

What is meant by the "Transparent UART" function in connection  with BLE? I have found this expression for the Dual BT Chip RF 4677. The Datasheet say's:

> It supports GAP, SDP, SPP, and
>   GATT profiles. Data is transferred over the Bluetooth
>   link by sending/receiving data via transparent UART
>   mode, making it easy to integrate with any processor or
>   Microcontroller with a UART interface. Configuration is
>   made easy using a ASCII commands via UART.
>   Windows® based GUI, or PIC MCU configuration driver
>   are also used to access configuration settings over
>   UART.

Comment: The way that serial data is typically transmitted in a BLE device is via a pair of GATT characteristics - one for send data and one for receive. These characteristics are mapped to the send/receive pins in the BLE chip and can be connected to a microcontroller. The microcontroller can simply send and receive serial data without being aware that Bluetooth is involved - the Bluetooth link is transparent.

Comment: Okay thanks, for this explanation! But how can I send and receive some data in my iOS app? I have searched in every documentation I could find but I have never seen a documentation about the used services and characteristics. So how can I handle this "transparent" mode in my app?

Comment: You need to identify the service and characteristics that are used for send/receive.  You then write to the send characteristic in your app and the bluetooth chip will send that data via the hardware serial port.  You set up a notify on the receive characteristic and then you will be notified whenever data is written to the hardware serial port

Comment: If you have the module you can use an app like LightBlue to see what services and characteristics it exposes